# compareTo() Method issue in program

Tags: java

I am trying to use the compareTo() method in java to compare 
a "level" of strings.

They go in order of sophistication as follows:apprentice, wizard, mage, sorcerer, shaman

However, when trying to use the compareTo() method, my results were negative (or positive) numbers when comparing the levels, even when they were the same.

Is there another method that I can use that will execute the proper if statement 
when a level is compared to another level that is lower, equal, or higher in sophistication ? Or will I have to execute a chain of if statement parameters to match each level ?

```
String otherLevel = m.level;
  String lowcaseLevel = otherLevel.toLowerCase();
  int result = level.compareTo(lowcaseLevel);

  if (result < 0){

     health = health + (m.health *.02);

     m.health = (m.health - (m.health *.02)); }

  else
  {


     if(result == 0){

        health = health + (m.health * .05);

        m.health = m.health - (m.health * .05); 
        {

           if (m.health > (10 * lengthOfTime)){

              health = health + (10 * lengthOfTime);}

           else   
           {
              if (m.health < (10 * lengthOfTime)){

                 health = health + m.health;

                 m.health = 0; }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Why do you have a random `{}` block in your method? It's really not necessary.

Comment: "They go in order of sophistication as follows:apprentice, wizard, mage, sorcerer, shaman" <-- this ordering is not the _natural ordering_ of such strings -- and what is `m` in the code above? What is `m.level`?

Comment: compareTo() probably wouldn't be your best bet here since it is not in any natural order that this method would generally accept.

Comment: @DanielRuf enums are very special with regards to ordering... But yes, it is a solution

Comment: @fge sorry, this is only a section of coding. It refers to the level of an object that was already declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that there is an order of sophistication which is, in order: "apprentice, wizard, mage, sorcerer, shaman".

You certainly understand in an intuitive fashion that when string values are concerned, `wizard` is greater than `shaman`. This is what you could call *natural ordering*.

Therefore, natural ordering of strings is not what you want here. You need another mechanism. Java does provide such a mechanism: an `enum`. Sample code:

```
public enum Level
{
    APPRENTICE,
    WIZARD,
    MAGE,
    SORCERER,
    SHAMAN
}
```

Enums in Java are special. They implement `Comparable` of themselves (therefore `Level` above implements `Comparable<Level>`) and the order depends on the *declaration of their values*. Which means that:

```
Level.WIZARD.compareTo(Level.SORCERER)
```

returns a negative number since `WIZARD` is declared before `SORCERER`.

HOWEVER: should `WIZARD` be declared *after* `SORCERER`, the result would have been the opposite! The [javadoc for `Enum.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo%28E%29) mentions it (emphasis mine):

> Enum constants are only comparable to other enum constants of the same enum type. **The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared**.

To summarize: use an enum such as the above in your code!